# ESCPOS commands (ESW)

Tags: python, thermal-printer, escpos, python-escpos

Does anyone know how to calculate print area on EPSON printer, using ESCW command?
I don't know how can I calculate xL, xH, yL, yH, dxL, dxH,dyL e dyH.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhmIW.png)

I'm trying to configure a printer with 80mm paper for 58mm paper.

Comment: nH is the value divided by 256, nL is the reminder of that division.  So if a dimension is 300, nH would be 1 and nL would 44 (nH * 256 + nL = 300).

Answer (score 0):

You'll find those numbers in the specifications for your printer.
Please look for it.

Alternatively, if you have an EPSON printer, click the light blue button on this page where the printer name is displayed to display the possible values for that printer.
[ESC W](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=56)

---

By the way, you don't need to calculate to create a command.

The coordinates of the left/top of the area start position and the width/height are 16-bit values, and should be arranged in little endian in order.